# Boolean method is returning true everytime

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQL to compare a date of an event

```
public static boolean sameDate(String DateString)
{

   PreparedStatement statement = Application.database.newStatement("SELECT * FROM BookShift WHERE id = ?  IN (SELECT id FROM Class WHERE Date  = ?)"); 

    try 
    {
       if(statement !=null)
       {
           statement.setInt(1, main.id);
           statement.setString(2, DateTwo);

           ResultSet results = Application.database.runQuery(statement);

           if (results != null)
           {
               return true;
           }
           else {
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException resultsexception)
   {
        System.out.println("Database result processing error: " + resultsexception.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
   }
```

Whenever I run my program and try booking a new shift, regardless of whether it does clash or not it always returns that it does.

Comment: You should not only check if results is null, but also if it is **empty**.

Comment: Why would you ever expect `results` to be null?

Comment: If the user does not have any booked shifts with the same date. Well that was what I had in mind anyway

Comment: You would just get a result set with no rows. It wouldn't be null.

Comment: What should I put instead of null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the result set has any rows or not, not check if it is null.

```
 if (results.next())
 {
     return true;
 }
 else {
     return false;
 }
```

or, of course, just

```
return results.next();
```

Comment: It didn't seem to like the method hasNext() but results.next() worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Yes, just noticed that; sorry for the typo (which is now fixed).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, it is not generally correct to check if `results` is null. I don't have the SQL experience to tell you what `runQuery()` will return on a query that fails, but I doubt that it's null, I would expect it to return an empty `ResultSet`.

Checking if it's null first isn't a bad thing, and in fact is a good idea to avoid `NullPointerException` throws. However, it's not enough to just use that check.